# VB execute keystroke automatically

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a windows form that I am making that the user inputs data, clicks a button, and then the code executes. At the bottom of my code I would like for the user to not have to manually hit enter but rather my program "strike" the enter key automatically when that line of code is hit.

Can I use `InvokeMember()` to do this? If so how?

The reason I want to impersonate striking the enter key as a user is because I am trying to fill out a form like you would find on a website automatically. I am rendering the webpage inside my windows form. I then put the appropriate info into those fields by grabbing the html element ID. When this is done the button does not contain an ID but striking enter submits my data.

Comment: Why cant your code just call a method to do whatever you want rather than pretending to be the user to "stroke" the enter key?

Comment: The tags related to the technology would be nice too (webforms, asp etc)

Comment: You could try sendkeys... but it's a rather ugly answer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A better solution would likely be forcing the form submit action though

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendKeys`

```
Private Sub SK(ByVal KeyToSend As String)
    SendKeys.SendWait(KeyToSend)        
End Sub
```

Used like : `SK("{ENTER}")`

Here is link to class info [SendKeys Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)